# Which minecraft directories to transfer to local machine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to do the following:

1. Use FTP to download my world from the server.
2. Open the world in a 'single player' mode.
3. Build a structure using lots of cheats.
4. Transfer the world back to the server.

Outside of the structure I built, I don't want players to experience any change.
I don't have and I don't want any plug-ins or cheats on the server.

Which world files I need to download and then re-upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download all folders and files from the world folder. While you are editing the world, the server must be stopped, because everything the players do will be overwritten when you re-upload the files.